# jquery youtube retrieving description

Tags: jquery, json, youtube

How do I add to this code so it pulls the description as well as the title and the video in an iframe?

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var htmlString = "<ul>";
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/(MY USER)/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=3', function(data) {
           $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {                                     
                   var title = item['title']['$t'];
                    var video = item['id']['$t'];
                    video_link = video.replace('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/','http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=');
                    video_object = video.replace('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/','http://www.youtube.com/v/');
                    htmlString +='<li><p id="video_title">' + title + '</p><object width="600" height="450"><param name="movie" value="' + video_object + '"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="' + video_object + '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="600" height="450"><noembed>Browser does not support video</noembed></embed></object></li>';
            });
            $('#videos').html(htmlString + "</ul>");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="videos"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var desc = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the url in the getJson you will notice that the url expects an username and a method for callback. You're missing both.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/**(MY USER)**/uploads?alt=json-in-script&**callback**=?&max-results=3

You can read more about how to use youtubes api on their guides
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json

Comment: umm the code i posted works fine i just removed the username from the url, it's pulling the video and posting it to an iframe and the title.
All i need it to do is to pull the decription aswell...